# illegal state exception from startactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, illegalstateexception

Hi guys I am getting the following exception

```
ERR-5e1e9c7f83ba94b45017220ad632c|StackTrace:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Gallery{d6a81c0} not attached to Activity 
--------- Stack trace ---------
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:914)
mypackage.Gallery$openReceiptImage.onPostExecute(Gallery.java:1604)
mypackage.Gallery$openReceiptImage.onPostExecute(Gallery.java:1424)
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
------------------------------- --------- Cause --------- -------------------------------
```

My code is as follows

```
Intent fullimage=new Intent(mContext, Preview.class);
startActivity(fullimage);
```

Here mContext is `Context` and I am calling this from `Fragment`. Preview is `Activity`. I beleieve these informations are enough. And also I am not getting this issue always.

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of `context` ....

Comment: I think you use wrong context here

Comment: Thanks guys.... i'll check adding getActivity() instead of mContext. But i am calling it from Fragments... will it throw anyother errors

Comment: and also already asigning getActivity only to mContext

Comment: Context mContext = Gallery.this.getActivity();

Comment: when are you calling this `startactivity`? It looks like you called it already after fragment went away from activity.

Comment: in which method you're calling startActivity in?

Comment: i am calling in postexecute.

Comment: Vlad Matvienko can you tell me in what scenario fragment may be deteched from Activity? just for knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Issue is fixed

```
if(isAdded){ }
```

Is used to check whether that fragment is attached to Activity or not

Comment: Yeah it depends on how you are starting new activity.

Comment: Yes Tasneem Thanks